# How to solve this graphic problem in my Java Flappy Bird game?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, game-development, flappy-bird-clone

So here is a picture of my Flappy Bird gameplay:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8ReB.png]

And here is the code for the graphics, display part using Java Swing `JPanel`:

```java
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // Draw background image
    backgroundImage.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);

    // Draw obstacles
    for (Rectangle obstacle : obstacles) {
        int pipeSpace = space; // space between upper and lower pipes
        int lowerPipeHeight = 600 - obstacle.height - pipeSpace;

        // Draw lower pipe
        g.drawImage(lowerPipeIcon.getImage(), obstacle.x, obstacle.y
                + obstacle.height + pipeSpace, obstacle.width,
                lowerPipeHeight, this);

        // Draw upper pipe
        g.drawImage(upperPipeIcon.getImage(), obstacle.x, obstacle.y,
                obstacle.width, obstacle.height, this);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the below pipes are always looks not normal, I tried many ways to fix the code, but it just gone worse.

[Here](https://github.com/JoshiMinh/jm-flappy-bird) is the link to the game files on Github.

Most of the game code is in the Launcher and FlappyBird java files for anyone who wants to read the full code and I would love to wait for a god from the sky to descend and help me solve this chronic problem.

Comment: I can't see any obvious issues, so I can only guess that it is a rendering issue which is likely caused by scaling the image size. I note that the pipe images are not being scaled correctly, so the shorter pipes are being squashed (See the middle one up the top how the pipe lip is very thin, but the top left pipe has a very thick lip). I don't know why the top works but the bottom doesn't, but I have seen it happen in some scenarios. Consider instead drawing the image with a height that is scaled to match the width (rather than just squashing it), and let the pipe go off the edge of the screen

Comment: *As you can see, the below pipes are always looks not normal,* - define "not normal". I am not aware of the "Flappy Bird" game so I don't know what they should look like. Any question should include the desired outcome as well as the problem with the current outcome.